# iOS - touches not recognized after constraint added

Tags: ios, layout

In my iOS app, my parent view has a child view which, in turn, has a number of UIButtons as children.  Without constraints, touches on the buttons are recognized by the topmost view controller.  However, when I add a constraint to center the child view (the one containing the UIButtons) horizontally within the parent, the parent stops recognizing the touches.

First of all, is this the correct/preferred way to do this (centering a group of views - e.g. buttons - by putting them in a View)?  Should I be using a Container View, or stacked Stack Views, instead?  (I tried a Container View, but (a) it generated its own controller, and (b) for some reason, I couldn't move the buttons into the container.)

Second, how do I get the view to recognize the touches while maintaining the constraint?

Comment: Show code that reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is no code.  This is being done entirely in the storyboard.

Comment: 1. When you add subview in storyboard/interface biulder Xcode will add automatic constraints in case the subview(button) don't have constraints, but if you will add one yourself, Xcode will recognize that and won't add automatic constraints, 2. You can update your question with images how you did add the constraints and how the layout look like,it can help some one to recognize the issue and give you some guide

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was, I needed to set a fixed width and height as well in order to get the layout set up correctly.  Once I did that, it worked correctly.